# create a hyperlink which loads an external page followed by a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, hyperlink, external

I have a **[javascript](http://www.gibwork.com/Gibwork.js)** which I would like to activate automatically when loading my facebook group.

The code works fine if I go to my group on facebook and add it as a bookmark containing the javascript as its url.

I want to know how I can place on my website like i have tried to do so **[here](http://www.gibwork.com/gibworkadd/)** a page with a hyperlink "click here" which takes them to my groups page and later activate the javascript.

Some members are not browser savvy and take ages trying the method of creating a bookmark and making sure they click it whilst on the groups page or simply adding the javascript in the address bar. Just want it to be as automated as possible and have it as easy as clicking on a link on my page. This also works a charm in firefox so would be great if the code includes to use firefox.

I would state before clicking to download firefox if not already done so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> onclick="myFunction()"

So when you click on your hyperlink if will open yoru page and do what ever javascript function your want.

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="myFunction()" href="http://www.facebook.com/groups/gib.work">Gibwork Group page </a>
```

Comment: javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://gibwork.com/Gibwork.js';})();

this is my javascript. where would it be added and how would the code look in the above? Is there a way to delay a few seconds the javascript so it gives the browser a chance to load the groups page?

Comment: I did this but had no joy....all it did was open the group page but no javasript was activated after that..below comment displays what i had written out.

Comment: <a target="_blank" onclick="myFunction(javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://gibwork.com/Gibwork.js';})();)" href="http://www.facebook.com/groups/gib.work">Gibwork Group page </a>

Comment: please help with my last question...it would be very much appreciated if you could provide the complete puzzle in html code all together so I can copy it and test it on my end directly. I would also like to have a timeout for the javascript to kick in...this will give the page time to load due to internet connection. This code only seems to work in Firefox but I am not sure how i can avoid making users download firefox to make this work and be able to be flexible enough to load correctly in any popular browser..

If i get the above sorted, i will be the happiest man on earth.